# I cant figure out what my condition needs to be regarding characters

Tags: c, if-statement, char, conditional-statements

So I've been trying to figure out how to use the correct condition for my if statements (I know there is some ugliness with the code itself but I'm concerned with the conditions atm). I want it to go into the if statement whenever "theguess" (a character enter by the user) equals the "H" or "h" in the first if statement, if it equals "T" or "t" in the second if statement, and if it does NOT equal "H", "h", "T", or "t" for the third. I previously had || instead of && but that also didn't work. Please halp me

There is no problem with the input or storage of the character into the variable, only my logic is flawed.

edit: The reason i decided to try && is because it fixed a similar problem that someone else asked. Sorry for the duncey code logic not matching what I want it to do.

```
    if (theguess == ('H') && ('h'))
        {
            P1score -= 5;
            puts("-5 Points!");
        }
        if (theguess == ('T') && ('t'))
        {
            P1score += 10;
            puts("+10 Points!");
        }
        if (theguess != ('H') && ('h') && ('T') && ('t'))
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: 1. Your syntax is just wrong. Any basic tutorial will cover the correct syntax, just guessing won't help... 2. Your description says "equals 'H' OR 'h', but your code used AND.

Comment: Use this syntax: `if (theguess == 'H' || theguess == 'h')` and so on.

Comment: Tried using `else if`?

Comment: For the first if, `theguess`  equal to `H` OR `theguess` equal to `h`.Good Luck.

Comment: C isn't the best choice to learn by Trial&Error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it's about being to lazy to read a tutorial ... :/

Comment: I apologize for the bad question, I'm new to both the website and coding :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error here is,

```
if (theguess == ('H') && ('h'))
```

should be

```
if (theguess == ('H') || theguess == ('h'))
```

And why not are you using switch..case??

Comment: "Error here is" - what's the error? that's perfectly valid C. Please be more explicit.

Comment: obviously there is no syntax error but as OP needs to check if the value is either 'H' or 'h', the OPs statement will be treated as "if (theguess == ('H') && TRUE)"

Comment: I am using this code inside of a switch statement already and was trying not to confuse myself a bit. Thank you for the help. I did not realize that after the || you had to place the variable == again. :)

Comment: and obviously, that's *not* an error. It's just not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @babon-- sure it's an error; not a compiler error, but a logic error, or a coding error, or a mistake, if you prefer....

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check whether entered character is 'h' or 'H' then why are you using 'AND' operator ?

You have not given conditions correctly. Try as below it will work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    char thought;
    float P1score=0.0;
    printf("Enter your thought\n");
    scanf("%c",&thought);
    if(thought=='h' || thought=='H')
    {
            P1score -= 5;
        puts("-5 Points!");
    }
    else if (thought=='T'||thought== 't')
    {
        P1score += 10;
        puts("+10 Points!");
    }
    else
    {
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always check the return of `scanf`. If the user cancels input by pressing `ctrl+d` (or `ctrl+z` on windoze) you have undefined behavior from that point forward (you would benefit in that case from initializing `thought` as you did `P1score`). A simple `if (scanf("%c",&thought) != 1) {..handle error..}` is all you need.

Answer (score -2):

> Try this .You have to use *or*/|| because if you give capital or small letter,den it will satisfy.If it works, please give me alike.

*if (theguess == ('H') || theguess ==  ('h'))*

```
    {

        P1score -= 5;

        puts("-5 Points!");

    }

   else if (theguess == ('T') || theguess == ('t'))

    {

        P1score += 10;

        puts("+10 Points!");

    }

    else 

    {

        return 0;

    }
```